# "Automatic YouTube videos to site uploader"

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

Is there a way to automatically upload videos from YouTube to my site, so that when a specific YouTuber uploads a video to his channel, it will also be uploaded to my site, and keeps the older videos?
I do have the proper rights from the YouTuber to upload his videos to my website.

However, I did found a JavaScript that does that, but it deletes the older one, so you basically only have 1 video.

Here is the JavaScript I found:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" href="menu.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Pictures/favicon.ico">
<title>SITE NAME</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And this for the body:

```
<body>
<div id="static_video"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showVideo(response) {
            if(response.data && response.data.items) {
                var items = response.data.items;
                if(items.length>0) {
                    var item = items[0];
                    var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                    console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                    var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                    $('#static_video').html(video);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/YOUTUBER/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the API: `https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/` The code you posted only pulls the data for the current video and displays it on the page. It is working as intended.

**EDIT:**

I did some reading about the Google API, I found they had a perfect example to show you how to work with the data using jQuery. Here is the code, all I had to modify was the user to grab the video feed from. If you create an app that wants users to work with their channels you can use the API and get the key's needed, otherwise you can use the script below, it will load one video and thumbnails for the rest, it will let the user click the thumbs and load the video on your site:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Videos</title>
<style>
.titlec {
  font-size: small;
}
ul.videos li {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
ul.videos
{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left : 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  list-style: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay) {
  swfobject.embedSWF(
      playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&autoplay=' + 
      (autoplay?1:0), 'player', '290', '250', '9.0.0', false, 
      false, {allowfullscreen: 'true'});
}

function showMyVideos2(data) {
  var feed = data.feed;
  var entries = feed.entry || [];
  var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
    var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
    var playerUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url;
    html.push('<li onclick="loadVideo(\'', playerUrl, '\', true)">',
              '<span class="titlec">', title, '...</span><br /><img src="', 
              thumbnailUrl, '" width="130" height="97"/>', '</span></li>');
  }
  html.push('</ul><br style="clear: left;"/>');
  document.getElementById('videos2').innerHTML = html.join('');
  if (entries.length > 0) {
    loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url, false);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
    <object id="player"></object>
</div>
<div id="videos2"></div>
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/YOUTUBER/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=30">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if I read that correctly from their website, it uploads the YouTube videos to my website whenever a new video has been uploaded to YouTube?

Comment: That is correct, best part it's from the source, and it's proper use of the API.

Comment: Aaah, oké, I will take a look at it and try it out. I will come back if it worked. :)

Comment: Are other people able to watch the videos too, and is there some sort of tutorial for me?

Comment: Yes other people can watch the video as well, if you look on the left side of the page you will see the different languages available with samples, it's pretty cut and dry. (:

Comment: I have no idea how to install that, I am way too lost. :(

Comment: You don't have to install anything, you just choose the language you wish to work with and add the source code to your website. This is basically like embedding the video on your website but more than one at a time and automatically.

Comment: The thing is, I do not know what you are talking about with languages on the left side of the page, because I do not have that as you can see; http://prntscr.com/3em92e http://prntscr.com/3em9ro

Comment: On the left side under Code Samples, it list languages, you would choose Javascript and look at the examples to get an idea of how to work with the API.

Comment: Ooooh, I though language like English, German, etc. I am stupid. xD

Comment: It's all good, take your time and you will get what you want. (:

Comment: Now I have this: "This application requires access to your YouTube account. Please authorize to continue.", but when I click on "authorize", it sends me back to my page of my website.

Comment: @Blackfur I will do a test with this later today and post back here for you, I haven't worked much with the api as I never needed it but I will give it a go and see if I can help you figure this out, but teach you at the same time.

Comment: @Blackfur I tested the code and it works properly, grabbing more than 1 video.

Comment: Aaaah, you are a hero! I cannot upvote your comment, because I do not have the reputation to do so, but I would upvote it if I could. :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can embed a user's uploaded videos playlist:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=username" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

(change username)

Comment: The YouTuber who I want to embed does not have a playlist yet. :( And I already had an anwser. Thanks for helping, though. :)

Comment: Really? I'm was under the impression that it just automatically generates it from the user's most recent videos.

Comment: It uploads the most recent one and replaces the uploaded video before the new one..